# ElasticSearch Parent/Child query taking almost 10 seconds to run

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 6.4.2 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 - 3 nodes.

We have an index consisting of ~16 million documents with the following configuration:

```
{
    "2020-07-01-entities-prod": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "m_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "captureId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "capturedDateTime": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "categories": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "customCategories": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sourceId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "subject_captures": {
                        "type": "join",
                        "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                        "relations": {
                            "subject": "capture"
                        }
                    },
                    "subject_name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "refresh_interval": "30s",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "2020-07-01-entities-prod",
                "creation_date": "1593644234470",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "3f",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6040299"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query we are running is to get a list of `subject_name`'s , which each contain their own list of `captureId`'s:

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "subject_name": "Donald Trump"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "capture",
                        "score_mode": "none",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": {
                                    "match_all": {}
                                },
                                "filter": []
                            }
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "size": 100,
                            "_source": {
                                "includes": [
                                    "captureId"
                                ]
                            },
                            "sort": {
                                "captureId": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is the query is taking 9-10 seconds to run.

We are new to parent/child queries and we did read that they can be slow, but we weren't sure what "slow" truly means in ElasticSearch world - for some, 2 seconds might be considered slow for ElasticSearch, whereas 2 seconds is just fine for us - but 10 seconds, definitely too long.

Before we abandon the parent/child approach, I wanted to check and see if anyone can offer any tweaks to the query that we may be missing to get it to return faster.

We removed the `sort` clause as a test and that didn't make any difference.

**EDIT #1:** here is an example of the results payload just for visualization purposes. The full results payload is about 19KB and 18k lines of JSON.

```
{
   "took":10721,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":1,
      "successful":1,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":9013092,
      "max_score":null,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"2020-07-01-entities-prod",
            "_type":"m_doc",
            "_id":"188",
            "_score":null,
            "_source":{
               "subject_name":"Donald Trump",
               "subject_captures":"subject"
            },
            "inner_hits":{
               "capture":{
                  "hits":{
                     "total":895099,
                     "max_score":null,
                     "hits":[
                        {
                           "_index":"2020-07-01-entities-prod",
                           "_type":"m_doc",
                           "_id":"23580725-188",
                           "_score":null,
                           "_routing":"1",
                           "_source":{
                              "captureId":23580725
                           },
                           "sort":[
                              23580725
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "_index":"2020-07-01-entities-prod",
                           "_type":"m_doc",
                           "_id":"23580289-188",
                           "_score":null,
                           "_routing":"1",
                           "_source":{
                              "captureId":23580289
                           },
                           "sort":[
                              23580289
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "_index":"2020-07-01-entities-prod",
                           "_type":"m_doc",
                           "_id":"23580237-188",
                           "_score":null,
                           "_routing":"1",
                           "_source":{
                              "captureId":23580237
                           },
                           "sort":[
                              23580237
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: You've used single shard `"number_of_shards": "1"` for 16 mil documents. Could you please let me know more about your cluster details. How many nodes you have and if you can try changing the shard to say 3 or 5 and see if that speed things up a bit. Perhaps this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) can help. Note the section `how does shard size affect performance` in that link.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal thanks for your reply.  It's interesting you bring up shards b/c we have gone back and forth a bit. Some recommendations say to choose number of shards based on GB, and some say based on number of nodes.  We have been following the per GB recommendations up until now. The cluster we are using is 3 nodes.  I have updated this in the main post.  We will try with 3 shards and see if any difference.

Comment: Yeah its kinda tricky, but one point of concern when it comes to parent-child join in ES is that you would have to make sure child and parent docs are in same shard.

Comment: Ooooh ok I see.  I'm not sure if we can do that.